# How to edit remote images in CamanJS

Tags: javascript, php, proxy, camanjs

The documentation says

> CamanJS comes with a PHP proxy (you're welcome to add a proxy in the language of your choice) that you can use in the proxies folder. Before you use CamanJS for editing, all you have to do to enable the proxy is:

```
// Will use the PHP proxy in the proxies folder.
Caman.remoteProxy = Caman.IO.useProxy('php');

// You can also specify a URL instead of calling useProxy().
// This will call /proxies/proxy.php?camanProxyUrl={url}
Caman.remoteProxy = "/proxies/proxy.php";
```

After reading it I wrote following code

```
<script>
Caman.remoteProxy = Caman.IO.useProxy('php');
more javaScript here.
</script>
```

The browser how ever says unable to edit for security reasons. Am I writing it wrong? Do I have to include a php file somewhere. Where is that PHP file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to host the PHP script (available in the [proxies](https://github.com/meltingice/CamanJS/blob/master/proxies/caman_proxy.php) folder in the repository) on a server such that it's available on the exact same domain as the page that is serving CamanJS. This script will proxy the image data from the remote source to the browser in order to circumvent this restriction. Of course, you're not restricted to using the provided PHP script. You can use any server-side language you want, as long as it does the same thing.

Alternatively, if you have control over the source, you can add a Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) header to the server response, which will tell the browser that the image can be used despite the differing domains.